# How to remove notification icon from notification bar in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have just started to learn `Android` app development and get stuck into some serious problem that is, I need to remove a icon (for a specific notification id) from notification bar when some one slide down the notification tray.

I read some blogs and most of them are saying that it is not possible. Is it possible? If yes, then please give me some hint.

Preferable Android 2.3 and above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to really remove the notification without root, except asking the user to do so in system settings (4.1+). More info here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56020/how-to-hide-status-bar-notification-icons

On an app I developed, I provide a shortcut to such settings, and I suggest the user to do so, because I need the notification to keep my service alive.

Comment: Oops! then any tweaks?
But we can disable the notification icon from notification tray by clicking on it..

Comment: Afaik, no tweaks there. It's a security feature to avoid rogue apps.